# SAP HANA get referenced values from another table

Tags: sql, hana

DB: **SAP HANA**

**I want table A lookup name and age in table B**

What's the most efficient way if there is not only name and age but many column i need to lookup ?

TABLE A

| ID | QTY |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 20 |

TABLE B

| ID | NAME | AGE | TAG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SAM | 22 | 31 |
| 1 | SAM | 22 | 22 |
| 2 | TOM | 25 | 10 |
| 2 | TOM | 25 | 52 |
| 2 | TOM | 25 | 73 |

EXPECTED RESULT

| ID | QTY | AGE | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 22 | SAM |
| 2 | 20 | 25 | TOM |

Comment: Just `JOIN` the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with your data model, if you have columns such as `age` and `name` repeating.  You can do what you want using:

```
select distinct a.*, b.age, b.name
from a join
     b
     on a.id = b.id;
```

Alternatively, you could phrase this as:

```
select a.*, b.age, b.name
from a join
     (select distinct id, name, age
      from b
     ) b
     on a.id = b.id;
```

You would have to test which is faster on your data.  Performance depends on the size of the tables, the number of matches, and available indexes.